# Failed to pull docker image from gitlab docker registry

Tags: docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I am running a cicd pipeline with gitlab ,but its giving me following error
[image]

Please anyone can guide me where I am doing wrong .I have another pipe line on different repo its working fine .
Thanks

Comment: There's not enough information here to answer your question. How did you configure docker authentication for this runner/project? What settings have you changed compared to the project that works? Are you using the same runner? If you're self-hosting your runner, what are your runner settings?